# How do I force rbenv ruby version to use a specific rubygems version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I have a legacy project which requires ruby 1.8.7.

I've just moved from Mac OS 10.8 to 10.12, so I've installed rbenv to allow me to run ruby 1.8.7.

However, the gems I need require a file - gem_original_require.rb - which isn't present in rubygems 2.6.x.

My old 1.8.7 set up uses rubygems 1.3.6, so I would like to use this version of gems in this project.

Under 1.8.7, I've tried `gem install -v 1.3.6 rubygems-update` and `rbenv rehash` and I've restarted the terminal,

but `gem  --version` still outputs:

`> 2.6.10`

Can I set up rbenv such that each (project specific) ruby uses a specific version of rubygems?

Comment: The answer was here: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/UPGRADING_rdoc.html

`gem update --system 1.3.6`

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution - via http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/UPGRADING_rdoc.html

`gem update --system 1.3.6`

Has rolled it back to the right version. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command to update rubygems is the following

```
gem install -v 1.3.6
```

This will do it for all 1.8.7 rubies. If you want to do it for specify directories you'll need to [install the rbenv gemset plugin](https://gist.github.com/MicahElliott/2407918#enable-rvm-style-gemsets-optional).

Comment: Thanks - I think that's the same as I've already tried? If I type only what you've put, I get 

`Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)`

But although `gem install -v 1.3.6 rubygems-update` does execute (apparently) the install of 1.3.6, it's still using 2.6.0 when I do `gem ... `